# Nomenclature not appearing

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I'm struggling on getting my nomenclature to work. The funny thing is, when I take my entire preamble and set it in in another document I can get my nommenclature to appear, but when I use it in my project nothing appears.
Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={16cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C,CO]{\leftmark}
\lfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\LARGE{\title{P2 HV DC }}
\author{\textsc{Asger Nickelsen}} 


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\input{dddd/LatexAbstract.tex}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\mbox{}
\nomenclature{$V_{AB}$}{eletrical potential between two points}
\nomenclature{$\Delta$}{A diffrence between two reference points}
\nomenclature{$E$}{Symble for an electrical field}
\nomenclature{$r$}{distance between point A and B}
\nomenclature{$q$}{a charge}
\nomenclature{$\vec{}$}{vector arrow}
\printnomenclature

\input{ccc/acdchistory.tex}
\chapter{Theory}
\input{ll/KirchhoffLaws.tex}
\input{aa/diodes.tex}
\input{pp/Rectifier.tex}
\input{uu/ACDC.tex}
\input{Asger/capacitor.tex}
\input{qq/jk.tex}
\input{ttt/DiodeDiagrammer.tex}
\bibliography{Bib/kilder.bib}
\end{document}
```

This is what I've tried:

Putting `%` in front of all input files. Still no nomenclature.

Putting `%` in front of all usepackage except:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{nomencl} 
\makenomenclature 
\LARGE{\title{P2 HV DC }} 
\date{The 1st of February to the 19th of May 2017} 
\author{\textsc{Asger Nickelsen}} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle \mbox{} 
\nomenclature{$V_{AB}$}{eletrical potential between two points} 
\nomenclature{$\Delta$}{A diffrence between two reference points} 
\nomenclature{$E$}{Symble for an electrical field} 
\nomenclature{$r$}{distance between point A and B} 
\nomenclature{$q$}{a charge} 
\nomenclature{$\vec{}$}{vector arrow} 
\printnomenclature
```

In spite of this my nomenclature will still not appear, what is wrong? The odd thing is though if i create a new project using the exact same preamble, but in the begin document I only have the following:

```
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\mbox{} 

\nomenclature{$V_{AB}$}{eletrical potential between two points} 
\nomenclature{$\Delta$}{A diffrence between two reference points} 
\nomenclature{$E$}{Symble for an electrical field} 
\nomenclature{$r$}{distance between point A and B} 
\nomenclature{$q$}{a charge} 
\nomenclature{$\vec{}$}{vector arrow} 
\printnomenclature \end{document}
```

And then the nomenclature appears. Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of "pretty-printing" the LaTeX code; this was achieved by highlighting the relevant lines and clicking on the `{}` "button" immediately above the editing window.

Comment: In order to get the nomenclature you need to run `makeindex`. What are you using to compile the tex file? What compiling options are offered?

Comment: I'm using sharelatex and the only options I have is the following: 

Compile Mode

 Normal
 Fast [draft]

Syntax Checks

 Check syntax before compile
 Don't check syntax
 Run syntax check now